# Android Gradle plugin API for development

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-plugin

Recently I started learning about custom Gradle plugins. I am ok with it. Now I want to customize the Android build with my own plugin.

Below are my requirements:

1. I want to add product flavors dynamically to my Android app from my custom plugin
2. I want to configure the build tools version and other sdk versions from my custom plugin.

Is there an API google has released for this?

I have gone through the below Android DSL reference.
http://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/

What is the dependency I need to add to my custom plugin to use the above Android Gradle dsl APIs?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a dependency to the Android gradle plugin itself:

```
   classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
```

This will put the plugin in your classpath so you can reuse all the classes you want. There's no real documentation but you can always read the [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/build/+/master/gradle/src/main/groovy/com/android/build/gradle).